# How do you export Telerik .Net Maui Barcode as an image?

Tags: export, telerik, qr-code, barcode, maui

Anyone have any experience doing this? I generate a QR code fine but I'd like to allow the user to use it outside the app. I've found a few examples of how to do it in the Xamarin version such as:

https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/knowledge-base/barcode-image-export

but it depends on a package that is not compatible with Maui/.net7 and I haven't seen a comparable package to replace it with, or a ported example. There isn't a nice 'ToJpeg()' method for it unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you need the Telerik one specifically? Or you just want something to get the job done? I image if you generate a barcode with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4BRsdMc7OA and then export through this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAIbu496unE that could work. There might even be an easier way to export with the ZXing library directly.

Comment: MAUI has a built in [screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device-media/screenshot?view=net-maui-7.0) API

Comment: Well I have the Telerik control set so it would be nice if I didn't have to switch it out, but if I have to I have to.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks the CaptureAsync is what I needed. Apparently you can apply it to any element including the Telerik control. Nice videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on GeraldVersluis videos:

```
var image = await qrCode.CaptureAsync();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await image.CopyToAsync(ms);

    // write the bytes out somewhere
    ...
}
```